# How to disable jgd-dropdown?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using jgd-dropdown, no idea how can I disable or gray-out this object?
anyone has similar issue?

thanks
Jim

Answer (score 2):

Did you already find the answer to this? I came across the same need today and just added the following 2 functions to jquery.jgd.dropdown.js:

```
$.fn.enable = function()
{
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  $(this).children('dd').show();
};

$.fn.disable = function()
{
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $(this).children('dd').hide();
};
```

Then call them when you need them, i.e.:
$("#").enable();